# Where is the rest of the /scoreboard commands in mcpe

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

[image: as you can see there is only dummy am I doing something wrong if so how do I fix it]

I’m trying to make a pvp map but when I try to add a scoreboard objective there is only dummy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other objectives have not (yet?) been implemented in minecraft pocket edition. There may be some ways to make the required features "manually" with the dummy soreboard objetive.

For a kill count you could maybe (depending on how you set up your world):

- create a dummy scoreboard objective,
- make sure that everyone spawns at a certain position that they cannot get to otherwise,
- increase the dummy objective for anyone at those coordinates
- teleport them to where they should be.

Comment: If I did this it would only detect when a player died and in the case of this pvp map an unknown amount of players will be playing at a time. If there is no solution I will be extremely annoyed as I’ve been working on this for weeks now and have hired builders.

Comment: @Raderth What other scoreboard objectives do you need? Doing the above steps would work with an unknown amount of players (if you set it up correctly), but as I said in the answer, that would be a way to make a kill count work, it doesn't do anything else and it isn't meant to do anything else. It is an example.

Comment: Could I use realms and download onto console and then do it or is it the same story for console.

Comment: @Raderth It is definitely the same in everything considered to be the bedrock edition (like the pocket edition). I am unsure about the console edition, but as far as I know it is incompatible with the bedrock edition and it would not work. It is likely that the version for your console is also considered to be the bedrock edition.

Comment: @Raderth There are some tools available to modify the pocket edition, I do not have any experience with it, but there may be something that solves your problem.

Comment: @Raderth What scoreboard objectives do you need? There may be a way to solve those, too, though there probably is no simple solution.

Comment: bear I need playerkillcount

Comment: @Raderth I can't think of anything simple for that, it would get really complicated (if I can solve it at all) and it would still be unreliable and maybe increase the kill count of the wrong person. I suggest you look if you can find some good way to modify your game. Sorry